# Maven/Surefire can't execute Spock and JUnit in the same project

Tags: java, maven, junit, spock, maven-surefire-plugin

#### Env

- java

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_241"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_241-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.241-b07, mixed mode)
```

- maven

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3
Java version: 1.8.0_231, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre
Default locale: zh_CN, platform encoding: GBK
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

- [pom.xml](https://github.com/sunzy/spock-example/blob/master/pom.xml) -- Forked from [spockframework/spock-example](https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example)

#### Problem

I forked [spockframework/spock-example](https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example) add java test directory and HelloJUnitTest.java => [sunzy/spock-exmaple](https://github.com/sunzy/spock-example/commit/764dea6a373d66bc83512b16107c6e054538381c)

**the Spock Tests can execute,but JUnit Tests can't**

#### Snapshots

- **mvn clean test**

only spock tests!

[image]

- **mvn clean test -Dtest=HelloJUnitTest**

[image]

- JUnit Test had generate in **target/test-classes***

[image]

- **mvn clean test -Dtest=HelloSpocSpec**

[image]

- mvn -X include test-clasess

Comment: Move your unit test into a package a not the `default` one..

Comment: @khmarbaise  I created a package in **test/java** and moved the test into it , got the same result

Comment: Of course Surefire/Failsafe can execute Spock and JUnit tests together, if configured correctly and your directory layout conforms to the Maven standard. You posted an impressive amount of information, just not the relevant one: test source directory layout and Maven plugin configuration. While it is interesting to see the output in your situation, the input creating that output would be more interesting. Before I look into your GitHub project, one question: How experienced are you in Maven? I want to adjust my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, I have taken a look at your project. As you said, it is just the Spock sample project, upgraded to run Spock 2 tests. *BTW, it still should be upgraded further, because in the current configuration compilation does not work with current Java versions, but that is off topic here, I am just mentioning it because I ran into a problem and then downgraded to Java 8 in order quickly reproduce your actual problem.* The JUnit test's package name is not the problem either, even though the default package is always ugly, just like for the Spock tests.

Spock 1.x is based on JUnit 4, but Spock 2.x is based on JUnit 5 platform. This is also the one automatically found by Surefire when analysing the project dependencies. If you want Surefire to run multiple engines in parallel, you need to configure the corresponding providers as plugin dependencies, as mentioned [here](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/providers.html#).

In your case, just add this to the POM:

```xml
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
    <configuration>
      <useFile>false</useFile>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
        <include>**/*Spec.java</include>
      </includes>
    </configuration>

    <!-- Run Spock 2 and JUnit 4 tests in parallel -->
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire-junit-platform</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>

  </plugin>
```

It also makes sense to explicitly add a test-scoped dependency to JUnit 4.12 or 4.13 to your POM because JUnit 4.12 is only a transitive dependency in your current POM. But later Spock 2 versions might remove that dependency because it is not really needed. I think that already happened with 2.0-M3. So be careful.

After this change, Maven says:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M4:test (default-test) @ spock-example ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running HelloJUnitTest
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.059 s - in HelloJUnitTest
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running DatabaseDrivenSpec
[INFO] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.171 s - in DatabaseDrivenSpec
(...)
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 39, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

If you decide to upgrade from JUnit 4 to 5, maybe configuration gets easier for you because then both Spock and JUnit use the same provider. In that case please add a JUnit 5 dependency so your tests can import the corresponding test annotations and assertion methods.

---

**Update:** After @khmarbaise commented on using vintage engine and me fully agreeing that it is the better solution, I want to show you how to do that instead of adding plugin dependencies to Surefire. (So you can delete those if you want to use this solution):

```xml
<dependency> <!-- only required if you want to run JUnit 4 tests alongside Spock 2 -->
  <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
  <version>5.5.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Why version 5.5.2 and not e.g. 5.6.2? In order to avoid version conflicts and subsequent warnings about vintage engine not finding tests in the Groovy directory. This is just because the POM in this sample project still uses a Spock 2.0-M1 BOM. As I said, it ought to be updated. But with this version it just works because it depends on the same JUnit 5 platform version as Spock in this configuration.

BTW, now Maven executes the Spock tests first and then the JUnit 4 tests, so the log output for both would be in reverse order.

Comment: I would suggest to better go via junit-jupiter-vintage instead and remove the provider dependencies of maven-surefire-plugin. And go via JUnit Jupiter only...

Comment: You are right, Karl Heinz. Of course that would be preferable and also cleaner, feeling less hacky. My solution was a bit too quick and too dirty, I just fiddled with it for two minutes or so. I am still a Jupiter newbie.

Comment: I just had a few minutes to update the answer concerning JUnit 5 vintage engine. Thanks again, @khmarbaise.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  **surefire-junit47** and **surefire-junit-platform** doesn't work, but **junit-vintage-engine** works

Comment: If the first solution does not work, you made a mistake or changed something else. I cloned your project directly from GitHub and ran the tests there. Both solutions do work.