# Maven java junit test won't start with groovy spock tests

Tags: java, maven, groovy, junit, spock

I have a problem with running groovy test with java tests. I have java test in directory /src/test/java and groovy tests in directory /src/test/groovy and maven plugin config like it:

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            <configuration>
                <useFile>false</useFile>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    <include>**/*Spec.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>compileTests</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

But with this config only groovy spock test works without java junit tests.
What  am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance for help

Comment: I always recommend to take a look at https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: I changed my code base on your example and still works like before

Comment: It would be best if you could create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and share it, otherwise we can't really help you. FWIW I could execute java jupiter tests without a problem in the example project after adding the jupiter dependencies.

Comment: I agree that an MCVE is the way to go. You also did not mention if your JUnit tests are JUnit 4 or 5. That makes a difference Maven-wise (JUnit 4 means vintage engine, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63130530/1082681)).

Comment: Have you seen my [Spock 1](https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus/wiki/Examples#spock-1-and-junit) and [Spock 2](https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus/wiki/Examples#spock-2-and-junit) examples?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same issue and adding dependency to junit-vintage-engine, solved it, e.g.:

```xml
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
        <configuration>
            <useFile>false</useFile>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                <include>**/*Spec.java</include>
            </includes>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                <version>5.8.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                    <goal>compileTests</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```