# How to configure Surefire to include '*Spec' Spock tests?

Tags: java, maven, junit, spock

How can I make sure that certain tests are executed in a Maven build and not silently ignored?

I was recently forced to switch to Groovy 3. As a result, I updated my Spock version as well. Unfortunately, I missed the fact that Spock 2 requires JUnit 5. I only had JUnit 4 and Spock tests, therefore the Maven Surefire plugin used the JUnit 4 provider to execute tests. All Spock test were ignored. I just noticed this by accident.

I'm looking for a way to check if certain (or any) tests ending in *Spec are among the tests executed. I looked at the Maven Surefire and the Maven Enforcer plugin but could not find anything which suits my needs. If I'm skipping test execution completely this check should not fail.

Edit: This is a shortened version of the Spock example project as kriegaex suggested posting some pom.xml files. The problem applies to all Java projects, though. To me, a solution within the build process of the project itself would be superior to configuring CI/CD jobs as this can can easily be forgotten when moving/migrating the project to another CI pipeline.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spock-example</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>Spock Framework - Example Project</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <groovy.version>3.0.7</groovy.version>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <!-- Mandatory plugins for using Spock -->
      <plugin>
        <!-- The gmavenplus plugin is used to compile Groovy code. To learn more about this plugin,
        visit https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus/wiki -->
        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>compileTests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <!-- Optional plugins for using Spock -->
      <!-- Only required if names of spec classes don't match default Surefire patterns (`*Test` etc.) -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        <configuration>
          <useModulePath>false</useModulePath> <!-- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1809 -->
          <useFile>false</useFile>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*Test</include>
            <include>**/*Spec</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spock-bom</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-M5-groovy-3.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Mandatory dependencies for using Spock -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spock-junit4</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Where is the code? I see no application code, no tests, no Maven POMs. Like this, the question is only going to attract close votes or wild guesses. As for JUnit 4 tests with Spock 2, did you notice module [`spock-junit4`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.spockframework/spock-junit4)?

Comment: You are lucky I noticed your update, even though almost week late. Actually, subscribers get no updates when a question or answer is edited. So after an edit, it would be better to notify your communication partners by a new comment under the question/answer edited.

Comment: I would appreciate your feedback. You can either close this question by accepting + upvoting my answer or comment, if there are any follow-up problems. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the misunderstanding about `spock-junit4`. You only need that if you want to run JUnit 4 extensions, such as PowerMock runner, under Spock 2. If you want to run JUnit 4 tests **beside** Spock 2 tests, you need `org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.7.1` for Spock 2.0-M5. Adding that dependency, fixes your POM for me.

However, I took the liberty to upgrade to Spock 2.0 final, Groovy 3.0.8 and JUnit 5.7.2, all in harmony with Spock 2.0. If you use a default Maven directory layout and name your Spock specs `src/test/groovy/*Test` instead of `*Spec`, you can even do without the Surefire class name filter. You should however specify Java source and target levels. Without them, my JDK complained about the default 1.5.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spock-example</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>Spock Framework - Example Project</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <groovy.version>3.0.8</groovy.version>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <!-- Mandatory plugins for using Spock -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>compileTests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        <configuration>
          <useModulePath>false</useModulePath> <!-- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1809 -->
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spock-bom</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-groovy-3.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Required if you want to run JUnit 4 tests alongside Spock 2 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

P.S.: Actually, first I wanted to close your question as a duplicate of [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63130530/1082681). But because since then the version numbers have changed a bit, I thought I would post a new answer here for your convenience.

---

**Update:** You can make sure that both testes named `*Test` and `*Spec` are executed, by fixing the filter in your question by adding `.java` or `.class` extensions. Weirdly enough, `.groovy` will not work, which is a known Surefire quirk.

```xml
<includes>
  <include>**/*Test.class</include>
  <include>**/*Spec.class</include>
</includes>
```

or

```xml
<includes>
  <include>**/*Test.java</include>
  <include>**/*Spec.java</include>
</includes>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think this is quite useful for anyone wanting to run "old" JUnit and Spock 2 tests in parallel. However, my original question is a bit different: I'm looking for a way to make sure that tests with a certain name (*Spec in this case) are executed in a Maven build.

Comment: So I misunderstood your question twice. You should learn to express yourself more clearly. You wrote a lot about JUnit 4 and Spock 1 tests, then migrating to Spock 2 etc. Why all those words, making me write a lot in order to answer what I thought was your question, if actually the question is completely unrelated to your version upgrade or JUnit, and you simply have problems with the Maven Surefire include filter?  FWIW, I updated the answer. I took the liberty to adjust the question subject in order to reflect the real intent of your question.